# EF Core 5.0.x QueryFilter for Collection Property with ValueConversion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5, global-query-filter

I've got an `Url` entity with a string collection property which holds role names:

```
public class Url : BaseEntity
    {
         public ICollection<string> Roles { get; private set; } = new HashSet<string>();
    }
```

In the database this is a `string` field. It gets converted to the `HashSet` using a `ValueConverter`:

```
    var splitStringConverter = new ValueConverter<ICollection<string>, string>(
        collection => string.Join(";", collection),
        commaSeparatedString => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commaSeparatedString)
            ? new HashSet<string>()
            : commaSeparatedString.Split(new[] { ';' }).ToHashSet());

    var valueComparer = new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
        (collection1, collection2) => collection1.SequenceEqual(collection2),
        collection => collection.Aggregate(0, (a, item) => HashCode.Combine(a, item.GetHashCode())),
        collection => collection);

    builder
        .Property(e => e.Roles)
        .HasMaxLength(500)
        .HasConversion(splitStringConverter)
        .Metadata.SetValueComparer(valueComparer);
```

What I need is a global query filter for the Url entity like this:

```
builder.Entity<Url>()
                .HasQueryFilter(url => !url.Deleted && (url.Roles.Count == 0 || url.Roles.Intersect(_tokenAccessor.UserRoles).Any()));
```

where `_tokenAccessor` is injected to the `DbContext` and provides the role names from the current JWT token.
Unfortunately this query filter does not work because EF Core is not able to perform this query on the server:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(u => !(u.Deleted) && u.Roles.Count == 0 || u.Roles
> .Intersect(__ef_filter__UserRoles_0)
> .Any())' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect' failed.

But the `Intersect` method is not the main issue - the following simplified query filter is also failing:

```
builder.Entity<Url>()
                .HasQueryFilter(url => !url.Deleted && (url.Roles.Count == 0));
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(u => !(u.Deleted) && u.Roles.Count == 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Is there a way to access the `Roles` property in the global query filter?

Comment: I have bad news for you. It will not work. If EF can not create SQL for query filter - everything will fail. How to create SQL for splitted HashSet?

Comment: Maybe there is an option to additionally map the string field to a string property and use this property in the query filter?

Comment: This is much possible, but needs some SQL magic. At first, train to do this filter in simple `Where` query and if it works - you can move it to query filter. In my opinion, you should redesign your permission system, because queries without DB indexes support will introduce more pain in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I've now changed the database design. The roles are now referenced by a n:m navigation and with this approach I was able to make the query filter work.